# How to boil pork knuckle?

Tags: boiling, pork

My family would like to eat pork knuckle (ideally the Germany/Austrian style but not necessary as long as they taste fine).  I looked up various receipt but most require an oven, which I don't have (No! I do not have an oven!). I also do not have large enough fry pan - just one small enough to cook up the gravy.

I do have a very large boiling pot though; so I wonder in what way can I cook the pork knuckle just by boiling it and still manage to make it tasty. Should I add salt, tomato sauce, oil or what sort of seasoning in the boiling water? And normally in what way and how long it takes to boil pork knuckle to tender?

Some has suggest to boil pork knuckle in Coca Cola to make it tender and taste...Any creative receipt is also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was a child every christmas day we would have ragout des pattes de cochon (pigs feet stew) With meatballs in it. It is definetly possible to cook pigs feet in a pot!

That being said, I have never done it myself. This looks like a good recipe, you can get a good idea of what to do.

http://www.food.com/recipe/rago-t-de-pattes-de-cochon-pork-stew-with-meatballs-398226

Answer (score 0):

Indians call Knuckle recipe Paya - if you google "How To Cook Paya" - you will find many interesting recipes - all are boiled, not roasted - eat with roti (indian bread) or rice....  We don't each Pork and use lamb knuckles instead.  Best wishes